# MySQL auto increment for a row's value

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have rows like this for **users** table:

```
user_id | username | user_game_count | user_password | ...
2       | testUser | 19587           | testPW        | ...
```

I'm increasing user_game_count with UPDATE method:

```
UPDATE users SET user_game_count = (@cur_value := user_game_count) + 1 WHERE user_id ..
```

Are there any different way? Because when I use this method in a *real-time* game, **very fast**, it's giving results like this:

```
1
2
3 
3 (skipping)
3 (skipping too)
3 
3
8
...
```

(I'm very new to MySQL)

Comment: UPDATE users SET user_game_count = user_game_count + 1 WHERE user_id.. do not works?

Comment: I didn't test it but it must be work. What I want to say is there is a  "synchronous" problem. Maybe I solve it using MySQL commands like `AUTO INCREMENT` ?

Comment: No. Autoincrement is supposed to autogenerate an id value with an autoincremented value for a new row. Try to run your query inside a transaction, like Cartuzzi suggest!

Comment: I'm running it in a transaction, but still same problem.

Comment: take a look here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-locking.html